# Push Notifications in IBM MObile First: Which is better for sending push notification, MobileFirst Operations Console or via REST APIs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am developing hybride application with  IBM Mobile first(V7.1), We have requirement with Push Notification, For sending push notification which is better **MobileFirst Operations Console or via REST APIs**.
Please suggest ...

Comment: Definitely Mobile first if I have to use. Again it's depend on your requirement. What do you want to achieve like individual notification or group notification, event based notification etc

Comment: @Gagan, Did you used MobileFirst Operations Console  for dispatch push notifications.???

Answer (score 0):

In IBM MFP 7.1, it is not possible to dispatch Push notifications from the Operations Console. This feature is available from MFP 8.0.

You have the following options:

1. Use the server side APIs to dispatch push. This will be in your adapter logic.
2. Use REST APIs to dispatch push.

In an automated flow or in production, you will need to invoke your push dispatch adapters in a REST manner or use REST APIs themselves to send the notification. Both revolves around REST APIs. This also allows to automate the invocation using cron jobs or schedulers.

Comment: Thanks for update. Can you please share me information about sending pushnotification using   REST manner  and server side APIs to dispatch push

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_send_message_post.html

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage